# Привязка контента к одному (промежуточному) разрешению

Tags: css

Возможно ли при адаптивной верстке заморозить контент на разрешении, например 400px и чтобы дальше при уменьшении разрешения контент сжимался, показывая такой-же контент/структуру, но пропорционально меньшего масштаба? = чтобы не прописывать состояния для каждого из последующих разрешений. Спасибо!!

Comment: min-width / max-width    Если я правильно понял вопрос...

Comment: Если я ставлю min-width для блока на разрешении 400px, то потом при уменьшении разрешения(ширины окна) он вылазит за пределы окна

Comment: Так и окну минимум ставьте

Comment: Понятно) сейчас попробую поставить min для body и html. Спасибо!

Comment: обычно делают окантовку - wrapper. Отдельный див для всего содержимого

Comment: Сделала, теперь вся страница за пределы окна вылазят(

Comment: ну а как иначе? Если браузер в ноль сжать - то что? Хотите чтобы все сжималось до предела - смотрите на единицы [vw, vh](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)

Comment: Мне не до предела нужно - мне до 320px) Может в теге мета вьюпорт дело еще?  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale = 1, minimum-scale = 1"> Контент не уменьшается, он просто зафиксировался в размерах и вылазит за пределы окна

Comment: Выложите полный код HTML/CSS. На словах уже трудно оценить вопрос...

Comment: Такой вариант сработал <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">